# R: How to expand a data.frame based on nested results in xml file

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing

```
<StudyFieldsResponse>
    <StudyFieldsList>
      <StudyFields Rank="2">
      <FieldValues Field="id">
        <FieldValue>327635</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
      <FieldValues Field="Gender">
        <FieldValue>Male</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>Female</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
      <FieldValues Field="code">
        <FieldValue>55905</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
     </StudyFields>
    <StudyFields Rank="3">
      <FieldValues Field="id">
        <FieldValue>555828</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
      <FieldValues Field="Gender">
        <FieldValue>Male</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
      <FieldValues Field="code">
        <FieldValue>55407-1139</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>77030</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>90901</FieldValue>
        <FieldValue>23144</FieldValue>
      </FieldValues>
    </StudyFields>
  </StudyFieldsList>
</StudyFieldsResponse>
```

I have the above `.xml` file. I parsed it as follows in order to extract the `id`, `Gender`, and `code` records.

```
library(XML)
dat <- xmlParse(file = "example.xml")
final_dat <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = xmlChildren(xmlRoot(dat)[["StudyFieldsList"]]))
names(final_dat) <- c("id", "Gender", "code")
> final_dat
      id     Gender                      code
1 327635 MaleFemale                     55905
2 555828       Male 55407-1139770309090123144
```

However, notice that for the first row, there are 2 `Gender`s, male and female. Similarly, for the second one, there are more than 1 `code`s. How can I expand my data.frame so that the data.frame contains a unique row for each unique `id`, `Gender`, and `code` combination?

```
> final_dat_expanded
          id     Gender            code
    1 327635       Male           55905
    2 327635     Female           55905
    3 555828       Male      55407-1139
    4 555828       Male           77030
    5 555828       Male           90901
    6 555828       Male           23144
```

Comment: Strange XML ... What if second gender set contained male and female? Do you repeat four codes for both genders?

Comment: @Parfait Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex, nested XML, consider [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. On Unix (Mac/Linux), R can run XSLT 1.0 scripts by making a `system` call to open-source utility, [**`xsltproc`**](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/xsltproc.html). On Windows, R can run a parameterized PowerShell script.

Specifically, below XSLT targets the lowest level FieldValue under code and then retrieves ancestor nodes conditionally for id and gender, mapping through all nodes of gender with `for-each`.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/StudyFieldsResponse">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::FieldValues[@Field='code']/FieldValue"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="FieldValues[@Field='code']/FieldValue">
     <xsl:variable name="curr_code"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:variable>
     <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::StudyFields/FieldValues[@Field='Gender']/FieldValue">
       <xsl:copy>
           <id><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::StudyFields/FieldValues[@Field='id']/FieldValue"/></id>
           <gender><xsl:copy-of select="text()"/></gender>
           <code><xsl:copy-of select="$curr_code"/></code>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eixh2xD)</kbd>

**R**

```r
library(XML)

# TRANSFORM INPUT TO FLATTER OUTPUT AND SAVE TO DISK
system("xsltproc style.xsl input.xml -o output.xml")
doc <- xmlParse("output.xml")

# BIND TO DATA FRAME
field_values_df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc)
field_values_df
#       id gender       code
# 1 327635   Male      55905
# 2 327635 Female      55905
# 3 555828   Male 55407-1139
# 4 555828   Male      77030
# 5 555828   Male      90901
# 6 555828   Male      23144
```

---

Should you use Windows, consider PowerShell script

**PowerShell** *(save as .ps1)*

```
param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$xslt.Load($xsl)
$xslt.Transform($xml, $output)
```

**R**

```r
library(XML)

# TRANSFORM INPUT TO FLATTER OUTPUT AND SAVE TO DISK
system("PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File transform.ps1 input.xml style.xsl output.xml")
doc <- xmlParse("output.xml")

# BIND TO DATA FRAME
field_values_df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc)
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the .xml file is not stored locally on my machine but it's stored in an R object called `input`? How should I use `system("xsltproc style.xsl input.xml -o output.xml")` in this case? I tried `system(paste("xsltproc style.xsl", input, "-o output.xml")` but that didn't work. Note that `class(input)` is `'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument'`

Comment: Try saving that object to disk as .xml (see `saveXML`). Object appears to be parsed using `XML` library. Or check original source of R object. Pass that as input.xml for xsltproc.

Comment: I have 50k+ of these objects, so I would like to avoid saving them to a disk. Is there an alternative option?

Comment: That would have been very helpful to know in your original post instead of using `example.xml`. You can integrate this solution in a defined function and call it iteratively such as `lapply` to build list of data frames to `rbind` at end. Save each as temp.xml for xsltproc. XSLT is pretty fast for small to medium-sized files. Or add this step to the sourcing of those 50k objects.